# Is there a way to apply CSS to only a portion of the page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there a way to have CSS only apply to a portion of the page? And then I could control the amount applied to by using javascript? For example say I have a slider placed at 50%, I want the CSS formatting to only apply to half the page like so.

> **Never gonna give you up**
>
> Never gonna let you down
>
> Never gonna run around and desert you
>
> Never gonna make you cry
>
> Never gonna say goodbye
>
> Never gonna run around and hurt you

And then if I put the slider to say 90% I would get

> **Never gonna give you up**
>
> Never gonna let you down
>
> Never gonna run around and desert you
>
> Never gonna make you cry
>
> Never gonna say goodbye
>
> Never gonna run around and hurt you

Comment: well am pretty sure if we use different words and you show us what you want to achieve we can do it

Comment: Do you just want it to apply to a portion of the page, or do you also want to have that portion be variable depending on user input? If the portion is static you can use css by putting classes in the right place. If you want it to be dynamic you need to have JavaScript in the mix.

Comment: @TemaniAfif Uhhh well at the very least i would like to be able to have the style only apply to a portion of a <p> tag and then I could modify how much of that <p> tag it applies to using say Javascript.

Comment: @Bob Yeah I would like it to be dynamic. Sorry this is my first post so the quality is poor my bad. How would I be able to do that with javascript?

Comment: You can apply CSS design(s) by tags, classes or id's. Think how to separate your text accordingly

Comment: Your CSS would be in a class and using JavaScript you can toggle classes on and off for elements, check it out [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_toggle_class.asp)

Comment: @spirit Are you being sarcastic? Of course you can.

Comment: @GalAbra And, by location, pseudo-classes and pseudo-elements.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Of course I know how to use a <div> tag on a certain section. What I basically want is something to the effect of changing where the <div> tag ends dynamically using a slider controlled by javascript.

Comment: @TrustyPatches That would be much more involved than is necessary. See my answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CSS can be applied to literally any part of the `body`, but you need to have structured your HTML so that the parts you want to style can be found independent of other content.

If you want to highlight lines of lyrics one at a time, then each line needs to be able to be found as a single unit, like in the following:

```js
// Get all the div elements that represent lines of lyrics into an array
var lyrics = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(".lyric"));

// Get a reference to the range control:
var slider = document.getElementById("styleLyrics")

// Set up an event handler for the range control's input event
slider.addEventListener("input", function(evt){
  // Loop over each line in the lyrics
  lyrics.forEach(function(v, i){
    // If the slider's value is valid...
    if(i <= slider.value){
      // Apply a pre-made style to the line
      v.classList.add("highlighted");
    } else {
      // Remove the style
      v.classList.remove("highlighted");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.highlighted {
  background-color:yellow;
  font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="lyric">Never gonna give you up</div>
<div class="lyric">Never gonna let you down</div>
<div class="lyric">Never gonna run around and desert you</div>
<div class="lyric">Never gonna make you cry</div>
<div class="lyric">Never gonna say goodbye</div>
<div class="lyric">Never gonna run around and hurt you</div>
<input type="range" id="styleLyrics" min="-1" max="5" value="-1">
```

If you are going to want to apply styling to each letter or word, one by one, then you have to isolate that content with HTML just as the lines were above:

```js
// Get all the span elements that represent word in the lyrics into an array
var lyrics = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(".word"));

// Get a reference to the range control:
var slider = document.getElementById("styleLyrics")

// Set up an event handler for the range control's input event
slider.addEventListener("input", function(evt){
  // Loop over each word
  lyrics.forEach(function(v, i){
    // If the slider's value is valid...
    if(i <= slider.value){
      // Apply a pre-made style to the word
      v.classList.add("highlighted");
    } else {
      // Remove the style
      v.classList.remove("highlighted");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.highlighted {
  background-color:yellow;
  font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="lyric">
  <span class="word">Never</span>
  <span class="word">gonna</span>
  <span class="word">give</span>
  <span class="word">you</span>
  <span class="word">up</span>
</div>

<input type="range" id="styleLyrics" min="-1" max="5" value="-1">
```

You could even automate the creation of the HTML so it wouldn't be so tedious to write statically:

```js
// Create an array that contains each line of the song:
var lyrics = [
  "Never going to give you up", 
  "Never gonna let you down", 
  "Never gonna run around and desert you", 
  "Never gonna make you cry", 
  "Never gonna say goodbye", 
  "Never gonna run around and hurt you",   
];

// Get a reference to the output area:
var song = document.getElementById("song");

// will hold the string of output
var output = "";

// Loop through the array (lines of the song):
lyrics.forEach(function(line, index){
  // Begin building a new div for each line of the song
  output += "<div class='line'>";
  // Loop over each word in the line by splitting the string at each space
  // (which returns an array) and then loop over that
  line.split(" ").forEach(function(word){
    // Add a span to contain each word
    output += "<span class='word'>" + word + " </span>";
  });
  // Finish up the line
  output += "</div>";
});

// Inject the string into the output area
song.innerHTML = output;

// Get a reference to the range control:
var slider = document.getElementById("styleLyrics")

// Get all the lines into an array
var allLines = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(".line"));

// Set up an event handler for the range control's input event
slider.addEventListener("input", function(evt){
  // Loop over each word
  allLines.forEach(function(v, i){
    // If the slider's value is valid...
    if(i <= slider.value){
      // Apply a pre-made style to the word
      v.classList.add("highlighted");
    } else {
      // Remove the style
      v.classList.remove("highlighted");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family:sans-serif;
  letter-spacing:.1em;
}

.line {
  margin:.5em 0;
  line-height:1.2;
}

.highlighted {
  background-color:yellow;
  font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<div id="song"></div>

<input type="range" id="styleLyrics" min="-1" max="5" value="-1">
```

Comment: In the final example, it is dangerous to build the HTML by putting HTML tags and lyrics into a string and then assigning it to `.innerHTML`. The HTML could get messed up if the lyrics have any special symbols in them. It would be safer a̶n̶d̶ ̶f̶a̶s̶t̶e̶r̶ to build up the `div` and `span` DOM nodes using [`document.createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement), [`document.createTextNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createTextNode), and [`.appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild).

Comment: @RoryO'Kane Safer, yes. Faster, not necessarily. But, point taken.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Hi Scott, once again thank you for the reply. I used everything you taught me on my first website! 

You can see it here: https://ee461l-hw3-196501.appspot.com

Only works on computer web browser, and it uses sound!

Once again, thank you so much.

Comment: @TrustyPatches Very cool - Nice job! Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you use JavaScript, you can get close. It isn't automatic that way. The way it works is that you have your slider in HTML: `<input type="range" id="slide">`. Now you need JavaScript to get the value of this slider: `var slide = document.getElementById("slide").value;`.

Now you can change the CSS of elements with some fancy if statements. I won't make mine complicated, but you can make it as complicated as you want.

```js
var slide = document.getElementById("slide");

slide.oninput = function() {
  if (this.value < 50) {
    document.getElementById("1").style.fontWeight = "bold";
    document.getElementById("2").style.fontWeight = "normal";
  }
  if (this.value > 50) {
    document.getElementById("2").style.fontWeight = "bold";
    document.getElementById("1").style.fontWeight = "bold";
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="range" id="slide" min="1" max="100" value="50">

<p id="1" style="font-weight:normal;">1</p>
<p id="2" style="font-weight:normal;">2</p>
```

You can look into it more if there's anything else you need.

Comment: Not sure why you start off with *Not really*, when what you are describing is exactly what the OP has asked for - - A way to style part of the page with CSS and JavaScript to determine how much of the page to style.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I started off with "Not really" because, although this does what the OP asked, it isn't dynamic, and the question, at least when I first answered, asked about doing this with just CSS. I see that the OP has since edited the question, and I'll change my answer to reflect that.